# How can I convert 10^18 numbers to smaller numbers without losing their uniqueness in programming?

Tags: fortran

I'm dealing with huge numbers in my code and I want to reduce their values without losing their uniqueness (the map remains one to one) is there any way can help?

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: maybe if you have a lot of duplicate values you could do somethig

Comment: What is the range of your numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention it, but I assume your are referring to integers and not to floating point values.

If your number space is 10^18 and every digit is relevant, then you can't reduce to a smaller number space without losing information.

You can fit `-9.2 * 10^18` to `+9.2 * 10^18` in a 64 bit signed integer. If you need to go higher you need 128 bit numbers (or a 'big number' library for your compiler).

If your data is unsigned, it fits in 64 bit integers (`zero` to `1.84 * 10^19`).